# FHIR - Firely .net SDK - POCO composition

Tags: hl7-fhir

What is the recommended practice for creating POCOs for use with the .net SDK? For example, if I have a resource that descends from ImagingStudy and I want to restrict it quite a bit (as well as change cardinality), is it best for me to create a new class (MyImagingStudy) that holds a private instance of ImagingStudy and only publicizes the fields I need to use? Or are there other more appropriate mechanisms to handle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't define your own resources, all you can do is profile them.  At this point, none of the FHIR reference implementations support generation of separate classes for profiles.  (Managing this properly for slices is really tricky.)  Typically implementers simply write to the base resource interfaces and then validate to ensure they're meeting the profile constraints.